# How can I output Unity3D debug log?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I heard of that unity3d would auto export debug log to a file, but I can't found it.

And in the unity console, the same debug logs are in one line; I want separate them so that I can know their order.

I want export unity3D's debug log to a file.

How can I do these in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is automatically written to a file that you can find about it in the official docs.

[Link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html)

For example, Editor.log's location ->

```
Mac OS X    ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log
Windows XP  C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data_\Unity\Editor\Editor.log
Windows Vista/7 C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log
```

P.S. It's not exactly the same as you see on the console windows.
But, you can extract the same logs because Editor's log contains them all.

Comment: It's not the same thing as the console output.

Answer (score 3):

This way can also open the editor log
[image]

Comment: Again, that is not the same as the output to the console.